# VIsual Studio 2022 Preview can't connect to an iMac to test MAUI

Tags: ios, maui

I'm creating a MAUI application with Visual Studio 2022 Preview. The application is built with NET8.

When I try to connect to the iMac to test my application, the function to *Pair to Mac* is still in this condition for a long time.

[image]

After 5/6 minutes, I get this error

> An error occurred while trying to connect to the Broker...
> A timeout occurred on client vs32224enric while executing a post for topic xma/agents

[image]

Is there anything I can do to test my app on an iOS or macCatalyst?

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble with this, too. I can only provide hints.

1. In case it worked before and didn't after installing the Preview, you could try to get back to your previous version and re-install.
2. I had lots of trouble in general connecting via WiFi with lost connections and so on all the time. I just bought a USB Ethernet Adapter for my Mac and connected my PC and my Mac via Ethernet-Cable which is waaay more stable, now. But, after installing the Preview, I found out that my Network Adapter was deactivated to share WiFi and so my Mac could not download packages and the process was stuck somehow.

In general, if you want to setup an Ethernet connection between your PC and Mac, I would recommend something similar:

In Windows 11, you can access the Ethernet adapter settings by following these steps:

1. Open Settings
2. Go to Network & Internet
3. Access Ethernet Adapter Settings and open properties of your Ethernet-Adapter
4. Configure Ethernet Adapter Internet Protocol, Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Settings:

   [image]
5. For you WiFi-Adapter set the following option so that this connection can be shared on your Mac

[image]

6. Also make sure these settings are activated

[image]

7. On your Mac setup your Network Connection to get a fixed IP address via DHCP like this:

[image]

8. Restart both your PC and Mac to make sure these connections are setup afterwards
9. Disconnect Wi-Fi on your Mac and see if works to browse the internet just via Ethernet over your PC
10. In Visual Studio Pairing use your new IP Address to connect your Mac

With this you can make sure that you can also download packages needed for Compile from your Mac via your PC over Ethernet.

Hope you also can get more stability in the Connection process afterwards...

**Other things you can try**:

- Delete your **.vs** Directory in your App Project Folder completed
- Delete **obj-** and **bin-** Folders completely
- Delete your **App Caches on your Mac** so that everything has to be downloaded to restart your App again (can take some time) - You might use a Program like CCleaner for Mac to get everything deleted more easily